# How to add description to lxd container?

Tags: lxd, container

`lxc list` gives a list of containers. When there are a lot of them it is hard to remember what are they for. Is there any solution to add description to this list ? eg. "*this machine is for apache and mysql*"

Answer (score 4):

One can control the columns displayed by `lxc list` with the `-c` flag. However, there's a predefined list of columns, and as far as I'm aware you can't add new ones. You can see available columns by typing `lxc list --help`.

There is, still, one tool you can use, and that's the `user.*` free-form key/value configuration option (see the [documentation](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/containers.md)). You may set your own keys with

```
lxc config set <my-container> user.<my-key> "<key-value-string>"
```

Then, you can either filter containers by these values, as in

```
lxc list "user.<my-key>=abc"
```

or you can read these keys *for a specific container* with `lxc config show <my-container>` (or, better yet, `lxc config show <my-container> | grep <my-key>`).

---

You can also remove such keys with `lxc config unset <my-container> user.<my-key>`, or manually with `lxc config edit <my-container>`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a description (at least in 22.04 there is). You can see it if you list the containers like this:-

```
lxc ls -c ndts46acP
```

You can set/edit the container description like this:-

```
lxc config edit <ContainerName>
```

And putting your description after the line that starts (that line already existed in my installation):-

```
description: <your-description-here>
```